# Not able to access admin console for an activemq instance running in a docker container

Tags: docker, activemq-classic

I have created dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install default-jre

RUN curl -O http://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/5.16.0/apache-activemq-5.16.0-bin.tar.gz
RUN mkdir -p /opt/apache/activemq
RUN tar xvzf apache-activemq-5.16.0-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/apache/activemq

WORKDIR /opt/apache/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.0/bin
VOLUME /opt/apache/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.0/conf

RUN echo './activemq start && tail -f /opt/apache/activemq/apache-activemq-5.16.0/data/activemq.log' > start.sh

# Admin interface
EXPOSE 8161
# Active MQ's default port (Listen port)
EXPOSE 61616

CMD ["/bin/bash", "./start.sh"]
```

I created a docker container like this

```
docker run --name activemq -p 8161:8161 -p 61616:61616 temp-activemq:5.16.0
```

I tried to run the admin console as follows

```
http:://localhost:8161/admin/
http://<IP of the Container>:8161/admin/
```

Neither of them works

Outside of the container, I installed activeMQ and tried to run admin console, it worked. Can anyone please help me with pointers on how can I get this sorted?

I fixed the above issue with

```
docker run --rm -d --network host --name activemq temp-activemq:5.16.0
```

But, I am still researching why the port forwarding is not working?

Comment: What's logged when it starts up? It should say its exposing the admin interface to an IP address. `http:://0.0.0.0:8161` Might be worth checking that and the `jetty.xml` has the correct binding in the `jettyPort` section.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. In AMQ 5.16.0 they've updated the jetty.xml for the web UI to use 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0!

I fixed it by updating the jetty.xml

update under "org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" in jetty.xml -->

```
property name="host" value="127.0.0.1"
```

to

```
property name="host" value="0.0.0.0"
```

You'll need to copy and overwrite this file in your docker image and it should work.

Comment: You can also mention to add the command `RUN  sed -i "s|127.0.0.1|0.0.0.0|g" $ACTIVEMQ_HOME/conf/jetty.xml` in the Dockerfile, that does the job and the AMQ is available from outside the container.