# ActiveMQ login screen is not showing when runs as a Docker image

Tags: docker, activemq-classic

I have create a activemq docker file and when  i start the image  i cannot log to the login screen. The url is http://127.0.0.1:8161

here is my docker file  you can also see the url in the log.

```
    # Using jdk as base image
    FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
    
    # Copy the whole directory of activemq into the image
    COPY activemq /opt/activemq
    
    # Set the working directory to the bin folder 
    WORKDIR /opt/activemq/bin
    
    # Start up the activemq server
    ENTRYPOINT ["./activemq","console"]
```

```
and here is the log from the console
```

```
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/java'
INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
INFO: Creating pidfile /opt/activemq//data/activemq.pid
Java Runtime: IcedTea 1.8.0_212 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre
  Heap sizes: current=390656k  free=386580k  max=5779968k
    JVM args: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties - 
Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/activemq//conf/login.config -Djava.awt.headless=true - 
Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/activemq//tmp -Dactivemq.classpath=/opt/activemq//conf:/opt/activemq//../lib/: - 
Dactivemq.home=/opt/activemq/ -Dactivemq.base=/opt/activemq/ -Dactivemq.conf=/opt/activemq//conf - 
Dactivemq.data=/opt/activemq//data
Extensions classpath:
  
 
 
 
 [/opt/activemq/lib,/opt/activemq/lib/camel,/opt/activemq/lib/optional,/opt/activemq/lib/web,
 /opt/activemq 
 /lib/extra]
 ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /opt/activemq
 ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /opt/activemq
 ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /opt/activemq/conf
 ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /opt/activemq/data
 Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
 INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@6be46e8f: startup date [Mon Nov 23 
 15:32:26 GMT 2020]; root of context hierarchy
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/opt/activemq/data/kahadb]
 INFO | KahaDB is version 7
 INFO | PListStore:[/opt/activemq/data/localhost/tmp_storage] started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.16.0 (localhost, ID:afee6bfb43ba-45805-1606145547047-0:1) is starting
 INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://afee6bfb43ba:61616? 
 maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector openwire started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: amqp://afee6bfb43ba:5672? 
 maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector amqp started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: stomp://afee6bfb43ba:61613? 
 maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector stomp started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: mqtt://afee6bfb43ba:1883? 
 maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector mqtt started
 INFO | Starting Jetty server
 INFO | Creating Jetty connector
 WARN | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@ab7395e{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http 
 methods for path: /
 INFO | Listening for connections at ws://afee6bfb43ba:61614? 
 maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector ws started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.16.0 (localhost, ID:afee6bfb43ba-45805-1606145547047-0:1) started
 INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
 INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://127.0.0.1:8161/
 INFO | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://127.0.0.1:8161/api/jolokia/
```

what have i done wrong ? Thanks

Comment: How do you run your docker image?

Comment: @AndreiStoicescu  docker run --publish 8161:8161 --detach --name bb activemq_custom:1.0

Comment: And what does it show when you try to access that url?

Comment: @AndreiStoicescu nothing. I think it cannot find the url of docker  I am not sure .Also  If i use developer tools  (network)  i dont see anything.

Comment: try to run it with `docker run --publish 0.0.0.0:8161:8161 --detach --name bb activemq_custom:1.0` and see if you can connect to  http://0.0.0.0:8161 or http://localhost:8161. Also can you add the output to `docker ps -a`

Comment: @AndreiStoicescu  still nothing .   But on dev tools i get for http://0.0.0.0:8161/ net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID and for http://localhost:8161/ net::ERR_EMPRY_RESPONSE

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009219/13566428

Comment: @AndreiStoicescu If change the port in activemq then it works. But i need the default port because of security. Is there any other way ?

Comment: from what i understood you can keep the same port but the host should be 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: @AndreiStoicescu  The Security does not allow this specific ip 0.0.0.0 .

Comment: since is running in a container i don't think it can be a security issue because the ip 0.0.0.0 is the ip of the docker container and not the host. you can try to map your localhost to docker container's internal ip (127.0.0.1) or downgrade to ActiveMQ 5.15.9

Answer (score 1):

As at ActiveMQ 5.16.0 the jetty endpoint host value was changed from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1, see [AMQ-7007](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-7007).

To overcome this in my Dockerfile I use `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "bin/activemq console -Djetty.host=0.0.0.0"]`

Comment: this CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "bin/activemq console -Djetty.host=0.0.0.0"] wont work .

Comment: without change the port on activemq settings file? I will try it. But still i cannot use 0.0.0.0 from security is not possible.Thats why i will not vote your answer. Sorry.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but explanation would be useful here.  If Jetty binds to 127.0.0.1, only processes within the container will be able to talk to it.  Jetty must bind to an interface that's accessible from outside the container.  0.0.0.0 binds to all interfaces, which is an easy fix.  To make it visible to only the container host and not other devices on the network, the exposed port could be mapped to 127.0.0.1:[portnum]/tcp.

Answer (score 1):

Activemq startup done by `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile, so `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "bin/activemq console -Djetty.host=0.0.0.0"]` won't work.

Correct usage with ENTRYPOINT is
`ENTRYPOINT ["./activemq","console","-Djetty.host=0.0.0.0"]`